# code-davinci-002 doesn't work in Azure Completions playground

Tags: azure, openai-api

in Azure Completions playground, when I choose model code-davinci-002, no matter what I input into the prompt text field, the scroll bar on the right side will just auto scrolling down quickly, I even cannot get the chance to click the generated button.

if I press F12, I can see it's requesting this URL and never stop.
https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track and I can see this kind of error :Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.05bbce037cd04318a37df543c2b6ee00.Exception

Anybody got similar issue please?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on testing, it seems there is a bug with `code-davinci-002` model in Azure Open AI Studio.

You can follow-up on the issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-openai-samples/issues/36).
Meanwhile it gets fixed, you can use Azure Open AI API to perform task with the model.
Below is sample code snippet for reference:

```py
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI
    
client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key="YOUR-KEY",  
    api_version="2023-12-01-preview",
    azure_endpoint = "YOUR-ENDPOINT"
    )
    
deployment_name="codex" #This will correspond to the custom name you chose for your deployment when you deployed a model.
    
# Send a completion call to generate an answer
print('Sending a test completion job')
start_phrase = "# Write a python function to reverse a string. The function should be an optimal solution in terms of time and space complexity.\n# Example input to the function: abcd123\n# Example output to the function: 321dcba"
response = client.completions.create(model=deployment_name, prompt=start_phrase, max_tokens=1000 )

print(start_phrase+response.choices[0].text)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks RishabhM, not sure how long will cost for Azure to fix the issue.